# TCP over TUN: SYN/ACK is received, but no ACK is generated, and socket remains in SYN_SENT state

Tags: networking, vpn, tcp, tunneling

I am tunneling an outgoing TCP connection over a TUN interface set up by a program I wrote. The TUN interface basically just relays the packets to/from a proxy server, with minimal modifications (source/destination IP/port, TCP checksum).

Running wget on an IP routed thru this TUN interface, the packets appear to be sent and received correctly (see the trace), but somehow the SYN/ACK that comes back from the server does not register with the TCP stack, and the socket remains in a SYN_SENT state in "netstat -t". Spurious retransmits are then generated endlessly (until timeout) in both directions.

Here are the commands I use to set it up:

```
ip link set dev tun0 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tun0 
ip route add 216.58.197.100/32 dev tun0
```

followed by

```
wget http://216.58.197.100
```

Here is the wireshark trace [pcap here](http://www.filedropper.com/missedsynack3):

[image: wget wireshark trace]

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the problem: I needed to compute the IPv4 header checksum for the incoming packets before writing them to the TUN interface, since I modify them.

Comment: To be honest, I though of that too, but since you were writing you were already dealing with that...why are you mucking up directly with packets instead of trying to put iptables to use?